# I lose 2 reputation points for each removed post or user

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, reputation, editing

When a user or a post I edited in the past is removed by a moderator, I lose 2 points of reputation.

I understand this rule for any user who earn 2 reputation points when his post edit is accepted by reviewing (for user with less than 2000 reputation points).

However, I have more than 2000 reputation points, I have the "edit questions and answers" privilege and I don't receive these 2 extra points for editing a post. In that specific case, it would be normal to not to delete 2 reputation points when the user has edited a post which is removed in the future.

What do you think? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug, but it is a little weird.

Even if you have the privilege to edit directly (which gains no rep), edits that you made prior to earning that privilege which gave you +2 rep will still affect your reputation -2 if the post you suggested an edit to is deleted.

In this case, a user was removed, and a post on which you successfully suggested an edit was removed with them. That's the -2.

This could display much less confusingly than it does in these odd cases, we're working on that. It took me a couple minutes to figure out what was going on here.

I'm marking this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) however it's something we do fully intend to improve.

Comment: Ok Tim. Thanks for explanation.